# Why do I get a syntax error when I don't declare a member variable as public or private?

Tags: php

I get a syntax error when I don't declare a member variable as public or private.  However if I don't declare a member function as public or private, it defaults to public.

```
// Class
class Building {
    // Object variables/properties
    private $number_of_floors = 5; // These buildings have 5 floors
    private $color;

    // Class constructor
    public function __construct($paint) {
        $this->color = $paint;
    }

    public function describe() {
        printf('This building has %d floors. It is %s in color.', 
            $this->number_of_floors, 
            $this->color
        );
    }
}
```

For the above code, try deleting "private" from the member variables and it won't run, but if you delete "public" from the member functions it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *a* keyword before member variables. That keyword used to be `var`:

```
class Foo {

    var $bar = null;

    function baz() { }

}
```

`var` is to properties as `function` is to methods.

`var` is deprecated though in favor of explicit visibility declarations. So `public`, `protected`, `private` is to properties as `function` is to methods now. Methods *additionally* take a visibility declaration as well.

Logically they could have chosen `public var $bar` as the syntax for properties, but went with a simple `public $bar` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth history and context.  It's amazing how much of a wealth of knowledge there is on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

From [The PHP online manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> "Class properties **must** be defined as public, private, or protected."

...and...

> "Class methods **may** be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public."

[Emphasis mine]

I'm not sure why this is, but it's just the way the language is specified.